# Prolog Code Example: Unification

Tags: stack, prolog, unification

From an old final for my class:

Here is some prolog code:

```
mystery(1, 1).
mystery(N, F) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    mystery(N1,F1),
    F is F1*N.
```

Question 1: What value is unified with P in

```
mystery(3, P).
```

Question 2: If a semicolon is pressed after Prolog produces and answer for mystery, and interpreter will eventually report "ERROR: Out of local stack".  Why dies this occur, and how could you modify mystery to avoid the error?

---

Question 1:
I get

```
P = 6 ?
```

Question 2:
If I press semi-colon to get all answers, I get an out of local stack error.
I'm not sure what this code is trying to accomplish or how to fix it so I don't go out of local stack.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have a question about "Question 1"?  Do you understand why the answer is 6?

Comment: I sort of get why the answer is 6, but I don't know each step on how it got there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The out of stack error is probably because, when you get down to `mystery(1, F1)` which resolves to `mystery(1, 1)` and ask for more solutions, you hit the next clause, which calls `mystery(0, F1)`.  At this point, it tries to find a solution, but the only clause that matches calls for `mystery(-1, F1)`, and that calls for `mystery(-2, F1)` and so forth.  This means that there's matches called for until either the first number wraps around to 1 or you get a stack overflow, since each pending match takes stack space.

Answer (score 0):

@David Thornley already explained why searching for more answers blows up your stack.  You could fix it by using a cut operator:

```
mystery(1, F) :- !, F is 1.
mystery(N, F) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    mystery(N1,F1),
    F is F1*N.
```

The cut here makes it so that if the first argument is `1`, the second rule may not be applied.